# .NET web service returning valid date in JSON, js says invalid date

Tags: .net, jquery, datetime, formatting

I have a web service that returns a JSON string, one of the properties of this string is a date. In debugging the web service I see`1/28/2011 6:21:02 PM`, however in the JSON string it is `2011-01-29 02:21:02Z` in Chrome this is being interpreted as `Sat, 29 Jan 2011 02:21:02 GMT`, in Firefox it just returns `Invalid Date`. My ajax success function looks like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
    var dt = new Date(obj.signupDate);
    console.log(obj.signupDate); //Firefox & Chrome: 2011-01-29 02:21:02Z
    console.log(dt); //Firefox: Invalid Date Chrome: Fri Jan 28 2011 18:21:02 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) 
    console.log(dt.toUTCString()); //Firefox: Invalid Date Chrome: 1/28/2011 6:21:02 PM 
}
```

So I'm experiencing some really weird inconsistencies between browsers and the formatting of the date time period.

Comment: What kind of web service? ASMX or WCF?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's support for parsing and formatting `Date` varies wildly between implementations.

You can refer to [this chart](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) for some of the details.

To work around these inconsistencies, use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library.

On the .Net side, it looks like your service is translating the local time of the server to a UTC timestamp.  If this is isn't the behavior you were looking for, you need to pay closer attention to the `.Kind` property of the `DateTime` you are working with.  Avoid the `Local` kind, especially `DateTime.Now`.  [You can read more here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Answer (score 0):

I tested with a web service method returning a long type and it works well.

In your web service :

```
private static readonly long UnixEpochTicks = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).Ticks;

public static long ToJsonTicks(this DateTime value)
{
    return (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - UnixEpochTicks) / 10000;
}
```

In JavaScript :

```
var date = new Date(data.d);
```

Happy coding :)